# PHP&html: emailing form's checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to make a simple form that sends the user input to my email. I don't know PHP so I'm having some trouble here. I can't make the form include the checkboxes' results in the mail. I tried several times but I can't make it work. It's in spanish, sorry for that!
Here is the code:

contactoformescritorio.php:

```
<?php
$where_form_is = "contacto.html".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

mail("MY@MAIL.com","Formulario de pedido de copias","Form data:

Nombre: " . $_POST['cd-name'] . " 
Email: " . $_POST['cd-email'] . " 
Tamanio: " . $_POST['tamanio'] . " 
Acabado: " . $_POST['acabado'] . " 
Incluir en la cotizacion: " .implode(',',$_POST['agregados'])."\n" . "
Foto elegida e información adicional: " . $_POST['cd-textarea'] . " 
.
");

include("confirm.html");

/*
 * Procesar el formulario unicamente si el usuario lo envió. En cambio,
 * si se accede directamente a esta página, redirigir al formulario.
 */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    function check_input_value($input_value) {
        // Remove extra spaces of strings (beginning and end)
        $input_value = trim($input_value);
        // Prevent XSS
        $input_value = htmlspecialchars($input_value);

        return $input_value;
    }

    // Obtenemos los valores que el usuario ingresó
    $tamanio = $_POST['tamanio'];
    $acabado = $_POST['acabado'];
    $tamanio = check_input_value($tamanio);
    $acabado = check_input_value($acabado);

    if (empty($tamanio) || (empty($acabado)) || (empty($agregados))) {
        echo "Error: sin completar";
        exit;
    }

    echo $tamanio . "<br />";
    echo $acabado . "<br />";

    // Muestra los checkbox seleccionados por el usuario
    if (!empty($_POST['agregados'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['agregados'] as $agregados) {
            echo $agregados . "<br />";
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: formulario.php");
}
?>
```

A friend helped me with the form so it may be a little messy as I copied and pasted some parts.

contacto.html

```
<form class="cd-form floating-labels" name="htmlform" method="post" action="contactoformescritorio.php"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Información personal</legend>
        <div class="error-message">
            <p>Por favor ingresa un email valido</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <label class="cd-label" name="cd-name" for="cd-name">Nombre</label>
            <input class="user" type="text" name="cd-name" id="cd-name" required>
        </div> 
        <div class="icon">
            <label class="cd-label" name="cd-email" for="cd-email">Email</label>
            <input class="email error" type="email" name="cd-email" id="cd-email" required>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Informacion de la impresion</legend>
        <div>
            <h4>Tamaño</h4>
            <p class="cd-select icon">
                <select class="size" name="tamanio" id="cd-size">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar Tamaño</option>
                    <option value="1">Impresion 20x30</option>
                    <option value="2">Iman de 6 fotos 5x5</option>
                    <option value="3">Tamaño 3</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <h4>Acabado</h4>
            <ul class="cd-form-list">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="acabado" value="mate" id="mate" checked="checked"/><label for="mate">Mate</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="acabado" value="brillo" id="brillo"/><label for="brillo">Brillo</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Agregar a la cotización</h4>
            <ul class="cd-form-list">
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="agregados[]" value="marco" id="marco"><label for="marco">Marco</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" name="agregados[]" value="envio" id="envio"><label for="envio">Envio (indicar direccion)</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <label class="cd-label" for="cd-textarea">Foto elegida e información adicional</label>
            <textarea class="message" name="cd-textarea" id="cd-textarea" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes are both of the name `agregados[]`, which makes them an array. You currently handle them via `implode`, then later with a `foreach`.

Before your `mail`, run a `foreach` like this

```
if (!empty($_POST['agregados'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['agregados'] as $key=>$value) {
        if ($key > 0) {
            $agregados .= ", $value";
        } else {
            $agregados .= "$value";
        }
    }
} else {
    $agregados .= "(nothing selected)";
}
```

This will set the variable `$agregados` with the values that was selected from the checkboxes, and if nothing is selected, display such a message instead.

Then, in your `mail`, replace the line that handles the checkboxes with the variables.

Replace:

```
 Incluir en la cotizacion: " .implode(',',$_POST['agregados'])."\n" . "
```

with

```
$agregados
```

Also, please know that your mail will be sent regardless when you enter `contactoformescritorio.php`, as there is no checking if a form has been sent to it. The check you are performing (`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`) comes after that.

---

As a final note, not one that's related to your question directly, your `select` has no require-attribute, so your PHP script exits if nothing is selected (where you are checking of one of the three statements are empty). Just put a `required` attribute in your select, such as this

```
<select class="size" name="tamanio" id="cd-size" required>
```

Then your `Seleccionar Tamaño` can be set to a line like this

```
<option value="" selected style="display:none;">Seleccionar Tamaño</option>
```

This will make your form more "user-friendly", and not make the user fill in the form all over again if they forget to select something from the dropdown. Just a tip, nothing you really have to do.

Comment: Hey! I tried what you said but I still can't make it work.
XAMPP says:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba portfolio\contactoformescritorio.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: agregados in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba portfolio\contactoformescritorio.php on line 29

I couldn't figure out what the problem is.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your `$_POST['agregados']` either isn't an array (is it a string maybe?), or it's not being parsed to your `contactoformescritorio.php`. Do a `var_dump($_POST['agregados'])` in the beginning of your  `contactoformescritorio.php` to check if it's an array or a string.

Comment: It seems it's not recognizing the  foreach()  statement, or is it? I continue to get this error when I try to use  foreach()

Comment: Check my comment above, it might not be an array you're using.

Comment: It returned    string(5) "envio"   (both "marco" and "envio" where checked)

Comment: Then your `$_POST['agregados']` is not an array, which it needs to be for usage within a `foreach`. Your HTML form for the checkboxes are named `agregados[]`, which makes them an array, meaning that your `$_POST['agregados']` is not an array.

Comment: So how do I make my  `$_POST['agregados']` an array? Sorry, I couldn't follow you

Comment: `agregados[]` should be an array, I don't know why it isn't. When I run that code on my server, it works as an array.

Comment: Haha, well, I don't know what to do. Can it have something to do with the `value` or the `id` of the `checkbox`? Is there any other way to do it, though `id` or any other variable?